# Не могу ввести ничего в поиск

Tags: windows-10

Сделал полную диагностику в 360 Total Security и появились проблемы с виндой. не могу повысить/понизить громкость через клавиатуру. пропал значек языка на панеле. в поисковике (на главном экране) не могу ничего вводить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также и тут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновление запустить не могу, точнее, при обновлении пишет, что не удалось настроить или завершить обновления windows

***хотя в безопасном режиме все функции работают***

что делать и как это пофиксить?

Comment: Откатится до предыдущей контрольной точки восстановления(Если конечно есть)

Comment: ее нет, как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Надо было ставить Линукс.

Answer (score -1):

Самый легкий метод - тупо сбросить винду